# Android 5.0 not downloading IMAP emails

Tags: email, nexus-4, gmail, 5.0-lollipop

my nexus 4 cell phone upgraded to android 5.0 lollipop, and now it doesn't want to download my POP3 or IMAP emails (used to work fine in Android 4.4)
It just gets stuck in "getting your messages" - even for 2 hours.

It does download my GMAIL accounts and Hotmail account properly.

I setup the accounts manually (as I always did in previous upgrades..it worked fine).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue on my Moto G 1st generation.

Below steps worked for me:

- Go to App Info of the app. Press Clear Data
- Open App to check whether mails have loaded, if still same message appears restart your phone.
- Check your app again and see.

Make sure Sync option is enabled in Data Usage of the email app.

I hope it helps!